# What kind of plant is this leaf from?

Tags: trees

Found this glued to my door. Curious what this might mean.
The leaf is colored dark green btw, pink is bug from my camera.

[image]

Comment: Maybe someone thought it was cannabis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a variety of chestnut or buckeye.

Comment: Yep. This is indeed confirmed to be a chestnut leaf. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely [horse chestnut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aesculus_hippocastanum) (aesculus hippocastanum) or a close relative.

What the person who put the leaf up wanted to express remains a mystery to me - perhaps just a kind of fall decoration or joke.